# Ant parallel performance

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, ant, mxmlc

I need to compile many similar SWFs in my project. I have ant build file, where I run `mxmlc` (flex compiler) tasks. To decrease general build time I want to run the tasks parallel. I have 4 core cpu.

```
<parallel threadsperprocessor="1" failonany="true">
```

If I don't use parallel compilation, then it takes **~12 sec** to compile one swf. But when I try to run it parallel (4 cores => 4 threads at a time), the compile time of each swf is **~20 sec** and while ant is running I have terrible lags of whole OS. **Important**: I've just reinstalled my OS (windows 7 64), and before it everything worked fine (no lags, fast 12sec compilation with 4 threads). By the way, if I set `threadcount="2"`, then it is also OK, but I want  to do it  in 4 threads.

I guess It might be some java memory issues. I'm using now (and used before) `-Xmx1024m -Xms256m`

Please, help me to configure my JVM to make my build fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed. Installed x86 JRE instead of x64. I have no idea why it didn't work for x64...

Comment: Maybe because `mxmlc` has not been upgraded to x64. At some point, the whole flash project should be moved to this architecture but...